# How to subtract the average value of a column from the same column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table of one column [20, 60, 40, 20] and the average value of this column is 35. I would like to subtract the average value (in this case 35) from the same column such that the resulting column should have [-15,  25,   5, -15].

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (LENGTH FLOAT);
INSERT INTO TEST (LENGTH) VALUES (20), (60), (40), (20);
```

The result of the MySQL should be [-15,  25,   5, -15]

Thanks!

Comment: "I would like to subtract the average value (in this case 40)" Why is 40 the average value here?  35 is the average here do you mean something else here?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The average value in this case is 35! I would like to subtract the average value of this column (i.e. (20+60+40+20)/4.) from the same column. Eg. LENGTH column has [20, 60, 40, 20] and it should turn in to [-15,  25,   5, -15]

Answer (score 2):

Using a subquery may help:

```
SELECT a.length - b.length_avg
FROM
  test a, (
  SELECT AVG(length) AS "LENGTH_AVG"
  FROM test
  ) b
;
```

You may need to fix the syntax ... I didn't test it ... but the idea is to execute a query like that ... If you want more info, google: mysql subqueries

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL 8+, you would do:

```
select (t.length - avg(t.length) over ())
from test t;
```

In earlier versions, I would phrase this as:

```
select t.length - tt.avg_length
from test t cross join
     (select avg(length) as avg_length from test) tt;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do shorter with something like this :

```
SELECT LENGTH-(SELECT AVG(LENGTH) FROM TEST) FROM TEST
```